# C#: геттеры - сеттеры без создания дополнительной переменной?

Tags: c#, ооп

Вопрос довольно прост, но ответа на него я найти не могу...

Смотрите. Очевидно, что я могу написать что то вроде

```
class MyClass
{
    public Item MyProperty { get; private set; }
}
```

Таким образом, у меня в классе есть "торчащее наружу" свойство `MyProperty` типа `Item`, которое я могу изменять только изнутри класса.

Услождним задачу. Пусть я хочу каждый раз при изменении свойства еще и кидать событие. Я могу написать что то вроде

```
class MyClass 
{
    public event Action<Item> OnMyPropertyChanged;
    private Item _myProperty;
    public Item MyProperty
    {
        get => _myProperty;
        private set
        {
            _myProperty = value;
            OnMyPropertyChanged?.Invoke(_myProperty);
        }
    }
}
```

Но... при этом мне пришлось "заплатить" за то, что меня перестали устраивать автоматические геттеры и сеттеры: я вручную ввел переменную `_myProperty`, которая мне, в общем то, совершенно не нужна.

Просто я не могу понять, как БЕЗ введения переменной переписать сеттер так, чтобы он не только "сетил", но и посылал событие.

( ну, то есть, воспользоваться "публичным" именем свойства `MyProperty` я, очевидно, не могу: при вызовах вида `get => MyProperty;` возникает рекурсия...)

Не подкажете ли Вы мне какое то изящное решение, без введения моей собственной `private` переменной?

Вообще, вопрос, скорее, теоретический...

Comment: При всем сожалении, сомневаюсь, что возможен какой-то третий вариант. Автоматическое свойство короче, но оно на то и автоматическое, что генерирует самые простейшие геттер и сеттер, которые исключительно возвращают/устанавливают значение поля. Если вам нужна логика, отличающая от предлагаемой автоматическим свойством - вам всегда дают право написать полное, но как побочный эффект автогенерируемое поле больше не существует, и вам нужно будет определить свое.

Comment: Если только что то в АОП  вам может помочь. Можете открыть для себя [PostSharp](https://doc.postsharp.net/inotifypropertychanged-mvvmlight), например.

Comment: Большое спасибо за внимание к моему вопросу, и за наводку на PostSharp! Интересная штучка. Правда, я пока еще не со всеми ништяками C# 9.0 разобрался...

Comment: [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847057/raising-a-propertychanged-event-without-adding-a-private-variable) похожий вопрос на enSO, вроде что-то похожее на ответ для вас там есть :)

Comment: При использовании автоматического свойства поле создается компилятором. У него даже название есть: `<MyProperty>k__BackingField`, вы даже можете получить и установить его значение через рефлексию. То есть создавая переменную, технически вы ничего не меняете.

Comment: Спасибо большое, короче, ответ короткий и дан в первых строках enSO: "You don't. You can't."

Comment: @S.H. в принципе, так как сеттер у вас _приватный_, то вам и не обязательно файрить событие именно в сеттере. (хоть это и самый правильный способ, конечно)

Comment: @АртёмОконечников - Вы правы, но в практическом коде, который я пишу, десятки мест, в которых изменяется это свойство... так что из сеттера лучше посылать событие, чем искать все такие места в коде

Comment: Кстати, прекрасный вопрос, почему так мало плюсов?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Конечно, можно!

Раньше было нельзя, но с C# 9 у нас появилась первоклассная во всех смыслах [кодогенерация](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-c-source-generators/), и добавлять реализацию свойств стало легко.

Кодогенерация — свежий проект, и покамест в нём есть ограничения. Тем не менее, уже сейчас многое можно делать. (Будет развиваться дальше как сама фича, так и поддержка её в Visual Studio.) На текущий момент вы не можете изменять существующий код, только добавлять новый. Поэтому сделаем так, чтобы программисту нужно было лишь объявить поле и добавить к нему атрибут, а свойство и реализацию отправки `PropertyChanged` взял на себя генератор.

За основу я взял вот этот [уже готовый пример](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-sdk/blob/master/samples/CSharp/SourceGenerators/SourceGeneratorSamples/AutoNotifyGenerator.cs) и лишь немного его изменил. (Полный код можно форкнуть [тут](https://github.com/vladd/CodeGenerationTest).)

Итак, добавьте к своему solution'у ещё один проект (назовём его, например, `GeneratorSample`). В проектный файл положите следующее:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" Version="3.8.0-3.final"
                      PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers" Version="3.3.0"
                      PrivateAssets="all" />
  </ItemGroup>
  
</Project>
```

Генератором является класс, который реализует интерфейс `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ISourceGenerator`, и отмечен атрибутом `[Generator]` из того же пространства имён `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis`. Положим такой класс в наш проект, назовём его `AutoNotifyGenerator`. У нас получится что-то такое:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Text;

using static Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SyntaxFactory;

namespace GeneratorSample
{
    [Generator]
    public class AutoNotifyGenerator : ISourceGenerator
    {
        public void Initialize(GeneratorInitializationContext context)
        {
        }

        public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Нам нужно заполнить оба метода. (`using static Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SyntaxFactory` очень пригождается при генерации кода на Roslyn, т. к. класс `SyntaxFactory` приходится упоминать очень часто.)

Для начала метод `Initialize`.

```cs
public void Initialize(GeneratorInitializationContext context)
{
    // регистрируем syntax receiver, который будет создаваться на каждый пробег генерации
    context.RegisterForSyntaxNotifications(() => new SyntaxReceiver());
}
```

Сам `SyntaxReceiver` объявим ниже вот таким образом прямо внутри нашего класса:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Создаётся на каждый пробег анализатора
/// </summary>
class SyntaxReceiver : ISyntaxReceiver
{
    public List<FieldDeclarationSyntax> CandidateFields { get; } = new();

    /// <summary>
    /// Вызывается для каждого синтаксического узла в compilation, мы можем
    /// проверить узлы и сохранить информацию, полезную для генерации
    /// </summary>
    public void OnVisitSyntaxNode(SyntaxNode syntaxNode)
    {
        // любое поле с атрибутом -- кандидат на рассмотрение
        if (syntaxNode is FieldDeclarationSyntax fieldDeclarationSyntax &&
            fieldDeclarationSyntax.AttributeLists.Count > 0)
        {
            CandidateFields.Add(fieldDeclarationSyntax);
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь, метод `Execute`. Он более сложный. Что нам нужно сделать? Во-первых, мы добавим в проект атрибут `[AutoNotify]`, чтобы не заставлять программиста самого определять его, или использовать какие-то библиотеки, где он определён. Затем, найдём поля, помеченные этим атрибутом. (Для этого нам пригодится список *всех* полей с атрибутами, который нам даёт `SyntaxReceiver`.) Затем, для каждого из классов, где есть такое вот поле, добавим `partial`-часть класса (для этого и сам класс должен быть помечен как `partial`), где определим недостающее свойство.

Вот что у нас получается:

```cs
public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
{
    // Добавить текст атрибута и вспомогательный класс
    context.AddSource("AutoNotifyAttribute",
                      SourceText.From(attributeAndHelperText, Encoding.UTF8));

    // получаем наш заполненный SyntaxReceiver
    if (!(context.SyntaxReceiver is SyntaxReceiver receiver))
        return;

    // мы создадим новую Compilation с атрибутом
    // TODO: в будущем будет разрешено добавлять исходники во время инициализации,
    // так что этот шаг не будет нужен
    CSharpParseOptions options =
        (context.Compilation as CSharpCompilation).SyntaxTrees[0].Options
            as CSharpParseOptions;
    Compilation compilation = context.Compilation.AddSyntaxTrees(
        CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(
            SourceText.From(attributeAndHelperText, Encoding.UTF8), options));

    // получаем добавленный атрибут and INotifyPropertyChanged
    INamedTypeSymbol attributeSymbol =
        compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName("AutoNotify.AutoNotifyAttribute");
    INamedTypeSymbol notifySymbol =
        compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName("System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged");

    // обходим поля-кандидаты, выбираем только те, у которых
    // действительно есть нужный атрибут
    List<IFieldSymbol> fieldSymbols = new List<IFieldSymbol>();
    foreach (FieldDeclarationSyntax field in receiver.CandidateFields)
    {
        SemanticModel model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(field.SyntaxTree);
        foreach (VariableDeclaratorSyntax variable in field.Declaration.Variables)
        {
            // получаем символ, декларируемый этим полем, и запоминаем его,
            // если он и правда имеет атрибут
            IFieldSymbol fieldSymbol = model.GetDeclaredSymbol(variable) as IFieldSymbol;
            if (fieldSymbol.GetAttributes()
                           .Any(ad => ad.AttributeClass.Equals(
                                          attributeSymbol,
                                          SymbolEqualityComparer.Default)))
                fieldSymbols.Add(fieldSymbol);
        }
    }

    // сгруппируем поля по классам, и сгенерируем новые исходные файлы
    foreach (var group in fieldSymbols.GroupBy(f => f.ContainingType))
    {
        CompilationUnitSyntax classDef =
            ProcessClass(group.Key, group.ToList(), attributeSymbol, notifySymbol,
                         context, options);
        if (classDef is null)
            continue;
        var classSource = classDef.ToFullString();
        var filenameHint = $"{group.Key.Name}_autoNotify.cs";
        context.AddSource(filenameHint, SourceText.From(classSource, Encoding.UTF8));
    }
}
```

Сам исходный текст атрибута и вспомогательной функци кладём рядом:

```cs
    const string attributeAndHelperText = @"
using System;
namespace AutoNotify
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
    sealed class AutoNotifyAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public AutoNotifyAttribute()
        {
        }
        public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    }

    static class NotifyHelper
    {
        static public bool Equals<T>(T field, T value) => 
            System.Collections.Generic.EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value);
    }
}
";
```

Теперь, нам нужен вспомогательный метод `ProcessClass`, который и создаст для нас необходимый исходник.

```cs
CompilationUnitSyntax ProcessClass(
    INamedTypeSymbol classSymbol, List<IFieldSymbol> fields,
    ISymbol attributeSymbol, ISymbol notifySymbol,
    GeneratorExecutionContext context, CSharpParseOptions options)
{
    // проверим, а не вложенный ли это класс?
    if (!classSymbol.ContainingSymbol.Equals(
                classSymbol.ContainingNamespace, SymbolEqualityComparer.Default))
    {
        // TODO: выдать дагностическое сообщение, что класс должен быть на верхнем уровне
        return null;
    }

    string namespaceName = classSymbol.ContainingNamespace.ToDisplayString();
    // будем класть наш partial-класс в то же пространство имён
    var ns = NamespaceDeclaration(ParseName(namespaceName))
        .AddUsings(UsingDirective(ParseName("System")),
                   UsingDirective(ParseName("System.ComponentModel")))
        .NormalizeWhitespace();

    // добавили использование System и System.ComponentModel
    // теперь определим класс и не забудем добавить partial

    var cl = ClassDeclaration(classSymbol.Name)
                 .AddModifiers(Token(SyntaxKind.PartialKeyword));

    // если класс не реализует INotifyPropertyChanged сам, добавим реализацию
    if (!classSymbol.Interfaces.Contains(notifySymbol))
    {
        cl = cl.AddBaseListTypes(
                    SimpleBaseType(ParseTypeName(notifySymbol.ToDisplayString())))
               .AddMembers(
                    EventDeclaration(
                            ParseTypeName(
                                "System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler"),
                            "PropertyChanged")
                        .AddModifiers(Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword))
                        .WithSemicolonToken(Token(SyntaxKind.SemicolonToken))
                        .NormalizeWhitespace()
               );
    }

    // для каждого из полей создадим свойство
    foreach (IFieldSymbol fieldSymbol in fields)
        cl = ProcessField(cl, fieldSymbol, attributeSymbol, context, options);

    // добавим декларацию класса в пространство имён
    ns = ns.AddMembers(cl);

    var unit = CompilationUnit().AddMembers(ns).NormalizeWhitespace();

    return unit;
}
```

Нам теперь нужно определить метод `ProcessField`, который будет добавлять поле к классу. Тут существует много возможностей для ошибок (например, повторяющиеся имена полей), мы их не будем отлавливать все, поскольку проект всё же служит для иллюстрации (а он и так у нас получается немаленький).

Мы не будем конструировать синтаксическое дерево вручную, à la [Roslyn Quoter](https://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/), а немного сжульничаем: просто сгенерируем текстовый шаблон, и распарсим его. Вот что у нас получается:

```cs
private ClassDeclarationSyntax ProcessField(
    ClassDeclarationSyntax cl, IFieldSymbol fieldSymbol, ISymbol attributeSymbol,
    GeneratorExecutionContext context, CSharpParseOptions options)
{
    // получим имя и тип поля
    string fieldName = fieldSymbol.Name;
    ITypeSymbol fieldType = fieldSymbol.Type;

    // получим атрибут AutoNotify у поля, и посмотрим, не указал ли программист
    // конкретное имя для свойства
    AttributeData attributeData =
        fieldSymbol.GetAttributes()
                   .Single(ad => ad.AttributeClass.Equals(
                                       attributeSymbol,
                                       SymbolEqualityComparer.Default));
    TypedConstant overridenNameOpt =
        attributeData.NamedArguments
                     .SingleOrDefault(kvp => kvp.Key == "PropertyName")
                     .Value;

    string propertyName = chooseName(fieldName, overridenNameOpt);
    if (propertyName.Length == 0 || propertyName == fieldName)
    {
        // не смогли создать имя для свойства? сообщим ошибку
        context.ReportDiagnostic(
            Diagnostic.Create(FieldErrorDiagnostic,
                              fieldSymbol.Locations.FirstOrDefault(),
                              fieldName));
        return cl;
    }

    // шаблон для декларации
    var declarationText = $@"
public {fieldType.ToDisplayString()} {propertyName} 
{{
    get => this.{fieldName};
    set
    {{
        if (AutoNotify.NotifyHelper.Equals(this.{fieldName}, value))
            return;
        this.{fieldName} = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(
            this,
            new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof({propertyName})));
    }}
}}
";

    var subtree = ParseMemberDeclaration(declarationText, 0, options);
    cl = cl.AddMembers(subtree);

    return cl;

    string chooseName(string fieldName, TypedConstant overridenNameOpt)
    {
        if (!overridenNameOpt.IsNull)
            return overridenNameOpt.Value.ToString();

        fieldName = fieldName.TrimStart('_');
        if (fieldName.Length == 0)
            return string.Empty;

        if (fieldName.Length == 1)
            return fieldName.ToUpper();

        return fieldName.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + fieldName.Substring(1);
    }
}
```

Нам ещё не хватает определения диагностического сообщения:

```cs
static DiagnosticDescriptor FieldErrorDiagnostic =
    new DiagnosticDescriptor(
        "AutoNotifyGenerator",
        "Cannot generate property for this field",
        "Property cannot be generated for field {0}",
        "Code generation",
        DiagnosticSeverity.Error,
        isEnabledByDefault: true);
```

Генератор готов.

---

Что же, давайте теперь его использовать. В проекте, к которому мы хотим подключить генератор, добавляем его как ссылку на проект, и изменяем проектный файл таким образом:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\GeneratorSample\GeneratorSample.csproj"
                    OutputItemType="Analyzer"
                    ReferenceOutputAssembly="false"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Пишем тестовый код:

```cs
using AutoNotify;

namespace TestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var t = new Test();
            t.PropertyChanged += (o, args) =>
                Console.WriteLine($"Changed value of {args.PropertyName}");
            t.X = 10;
        }
    }

    partial class Test
    {
        [AutoNotify]
        int x;
    }
}
```

Компилируем, запускаем. Должно работать! У меня выводится на консоль:

> Changed value of X

---

Что ещё можно сделать с этим генератором? Можно улучшить диагностику. Можно сделать из него nuget-пакет, чтобы не таскать его в форме исходников. Можно генерировать более изощрённый и более параметризируемый исходный код. Вы же программист, действуйте!

Comment: Это великолепно и достойно отдельной статьи! Большое спасибо от меня и от многих, кто это прочитает! Вообще, так немного людей умеет хорошо объяснять, что я прямо хочу Вам поклониться!

Comment: @S.H.: Спасибо на добром слове!

Comment: А студия будет подчёркивать и ругаться на свойство `X`? Или сможет понять что оно будет сгенерировано позже?

Comment: Ох ты ж какая крутотенюшка... не знал, спасибо огромное за материал!

Comment: @АндрейNOP: Нет, Студия не ругается. С её точки зрения, у неё появляется ещё один исходный файл с partial-куском класса, в котором определено свойство. В текущей версии Студии, этот файл не показывается, и в нём нельзя установить breakpoint, но это будет скоро добавлено/исправлено.

Comment: @SerafimProzorov: Я долго ждал, пока эту фичу выпустят, [с 2017 года](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/107). Это и правда мегаофигенная фича, но пока не очень распиаренная.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, в общем-то, аналогично, очень хотел иметь такую возможность.

Comment: В планах сгенерироавнный текст будет показываться (как отдельный файл/файлы), и код можно будет трассировать (но не редактировать, конечно).

Comment: Не хватает определения `attributeAndHelperText`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: Спасибо за подсказку! Добавил.

Comment: А также выложил полный код в репозиторий