# ValueTask - правильное использование

Tags: c#, task

прочитал [статью про ValueTask](https://habr.com/ru/post/458828/) - возникло пару вопросов
вот код из статьи:

```
int bytesRead;
{
    ValueTask<int> readTask = _connection.ReadAsync(buffer);
    if (readTask.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
    {
        bytesRead = readTask.Result;
    }
    else
    {
        using (_connection.RegisterCancellation())
        {
            bytesRead = await readTask;
        }
    }
}
```

оно вручную опрашивает, не закончился ли таск и если закончился, то делает все синхронно; не закончился - асинхронно.

и кое-что не понял:

- что это за странный метод `_connection.RegisterCancellation()`
- и разве компилятор не может сам вместо слова `await` сделать разветвление на синхронный и асинхронный случай. может, в новых версиях? может, специально такого в компилятор не засовывают?

Comment: В типичном случае вам достаточно просто сделать `await`. Если у компилятора будет разветвление, вам всё равно нужно предоставить две ветки кода — что делать в синхронном, а что в асинхронном случае. Чем это будет выигрышнее, чем простой `if`?

Comment: @VladD, не очень понял - ты предлагаешь писать ветвление вручную, потому что это "выиграшнее"?

Comment: Нет, я не об этом. Допустим, компилятор сам сделает разветвление — откуда он возьмёт код, который надо выполнять в синхронном и асинхронном случаях? Его придётся написать программисту, верно?

Comment: `using (_connection.RegisterCancellation())` представляет собой _какую-то_, не важно какую именно, дополнительную логику, которую нужно выполнить в асинхронном случае. Считайте, что это псевдокод.

Comment: @VladD, а, тогда - ок. но если у меня нет никакой дополнительной логики, то компилятор это сделает за меня или нет?

Comment: Если дополнительной логики нет, то `await` сделает то, что надо: получит значение правильным способом, может быть и синхронно, никакой проверки тогда не нужно не нужно.

Comment: Мне хочется побухтеть по поводу компилятора. Нам нужно развитое метапрограммирование, гигиенические макросы! Тогда можно будет легко и просто создавать DSL и "засунуть" в компилятор как раз то, что вы хотите. И ведь такие языки есть. Но если MS добавит макросы сейчас, то что ей делать в следующие годы? Не получится уже каждый год клепать новую версию языка C#.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, ну, в С есть макросы... классный язык - некоторые до сих пор на нем пишут. XD

Comment: В C текстовые подстановки. Я хочу гигиенические макросы. И да, я использую язык именно с такими.

Comment: если ты про то чтобы в програмисты сами для себя писали макросы, то лучше не надо - слишком непонятный код на выходе будет. а вот фича с генерацией кода от dotnet5 просто ОЧЕНЬ полезная. иногда хочется обычными атрибутами себе код менять - теперь это возможно сделать.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: Развитие компилятора, в частности, метапрограммирование, обсуждается [здесь](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/). Покамест идея макросов не нашла поддержки, и метапрограммирование ведётся на уровне [кодогенерации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1235304/10105). Если у вас есть хорошие идеи, пилите предложение (но желательно не просто «хочу как в языке X», а с аргументацией, почему на это стоит потратить время и бюджет).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ваш вопрос можно разбить на 2 части

- `Task` vs `ValueTask`
- синхронное завершение метода vs асинхронное

Сразу скажу, технически эти 2 части вопроса между собой никак не связаны, но связаны логически.

Будет код синхронный или асинхронный решает не компилятор, а вы. Чтобы внедрить асинхронную машину состояний в метод, вы явно указываете ключевое слово `async`. А чтобы добавить состояния в эту машину, вы добавляете `await`.

Если на пути выполнения метода встретился `await`, то метод выполнится асинхронно в случае если `await` получит из вызванного метода незавершенный `Task`/`ValueTask`. В противном случае метод выполнится синхронно как обычный синхронный метод.

Самый простой пример такого ветвления - узнать свой IP:

```cs
class Program
{
    private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    private static string ipCache = null;

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await GetIP();
        await GetIP();
        await GetIP();
        await GetIP();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static async Task GetIP()
    {
        Task<string> task = GetMyIP();
        Console.WriteLine(task.IsCompleted);
        if (!task.IsCompleted)
            await task;
    }

    private static async Task<string> GetMyIP()
    {
        if (ipCache == null)
        {
            string json = await client.GetStringAsync("https://api.myip.com/");
            ipCache = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Response>(json).ip;
        }
        return ipCache;
    }
}

public class Response
{
    public string ip { get; set; }
}
```

*Если в этом коде все `Task` поменять на `ValueTask` (кроме `Main`) - ничего не изменится.*

Вывод в консоль

```
False
True
True
True
```

Здесь первый вызов метода завершился асинхронно, а остальные синхронно.

А различие в том, что создать `ValueTask` дешевле и легче, чем `Task`, но он имеет свои ограничения. Например его нельзя ожидать одновременно в нескольких местах. В статье по вашей ссылке это должно быть написано. Я не читал ее, но читал оригинал, с которого она была переведена.

Итого, вам не стоит сильно запариваться о том, что там выдумал компилятор, но следует различать синхронное и асинхронное выполнение метода.

Использовать ли `ValueTask`? Не использовать, если ваш код не суперчувствителен к производительности. Например если вы пишете код клиентского приложения, можно вообще не думать об этом. А вот если вы пишете асинхронный код для сервера, который будет обслуживать много-много пользователей одновременно, то вот здесь вам `ValueTask` и пригодится как способ сэкономить на ресурсах.

Экономия эта будет ощутима только в случае высокой нагрузки. А чтобы ответить, откуда берется эта экономия, надо понять, чем значимые типы отличаются от ссылочных в плане производительности, надо понять, когда лучше использовать класс, а когда структуру, `Task` - класс, `ValueTask` - структура. Тогда и станет понятно, зачем это вся история с `ValueTask` была придумана.

Другими словами, безопаснее и проще использовать именно `Task`, используйте его по умолчанию. Если поймете, что создавать экземпляр класса на каждый вызов метода - это для вас медленно и дорого, внедряйте `ValueTask`, но это уже тонкости оптимизации.

Comment: Отлично написано, всё понятно )

Comment: <<Если в этом коде все Task поменять на ValueTask (кроме Main) - ничего не изменится.>> - не очень понял. при возврате кешированного значения можно же секономить память используя ValueTask вместо Task

Comment: @dgzargo `Task` можно точно так же закешировать. Не привязывайтесь вы к таскам, представьте, что у вас данные можно положить в экземпляр класса или структуры, куда положите?

Comment: @dgzargo если вы не готовы ответить на этот вопрос, значит вы не готовы выбрать между `Task` и `ValueTask`. Может ли `ValueTask` навредить приложению? Может, об этом я в ответе написал. `ValueTask` имеет ограничения, которые вам могут все сломать, и это будет не выброс исключения, в повреждение данных либо непредсказуемое поведение при гонке потоков.

Comment: @aepot `ValueTask` кешировать не нужно, только `IValueTaskSource<>` достаточно. отвечая на предыдущий вопрос: я бы использовал `ValueTask` при (`netstandart>=2.1` естественно) кроме случаев где результат ТОЧНО асинхронный. но тогда можно смотреть, кешировать `Taks` (когда их вариаций мало) или кешировать `IValueTaskSource<>` специально для извращенцев которые угарают по невероятно экономному использованию памяти.

Comment: @dgzargo `но это уже тонкости оптимизации`: сокращение количества аллокаций - весьма популярная задача оптимизации, и часто ответ на то, какой именно способ оптимизации нужно выбрать, дает либо конкретный участок кода, либо тестирование производительности. И то что `ValueTask` будет всегда быстрее и экономнее - вообще не факт. В некоторых случаях экономнее даже сделать синхронный блокирующий вызов вместо асинхронного. Все зависит от ситуации.